# How to generate migration to change database column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

I wonder if there is a way to generate migrations that change something in the same fashion as there is for creating tables, adding or removing columns.

E.g. for creating a table I would use:

```
rails generate migration CreateProducts name:string part_number:string
```

For adding a column I would use:

```
rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
```

I took this examples from the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) but I couldn't find anything for changing a column, let's say to set a default.

Comment: Section 3.4 on your link, "Changing columns"?

Comment: It shows how to set it up if you got a migration file, but I wanna know how if there is a task to create this file.

Comment: "rails g migration" -- or do you mean a scaffold?

Comment: `rails g migration` is what I am looking for, but one that sets the migration up for changing a column. In the examples I posted rails knows what I want by analyzing the name and the attributes ..

Comment: I don't think so. Scaffolding (which is what that is) is really beneficial for setting up lots of files, so when you are create a table/model with a scaffold it can create tests, controllers, views, etc. also. If you're changing a column then apart from writing the migration file there would not be a lot to do.

Comment: It isn't possible.  The [create_table_migration.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb) and [migration.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/migration.rb) templates can help build files with commands like `create_table` and `add_column` but not `change_column`.  Migrations that use `change_column` must be built manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Rails Migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html):

- change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options): Changes the column to a different type using the same parameters as add_column.

Example, inside your migration:

```
class ChangeColumnInTablename < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :tablename, :field, :string , default: <default_value>
  end
end
```